# jquery - lavalamp - image problem

Tags: jquery, image, caching, plugins, lavalamp

I have this menu where I use the jQuery lavalamp plugin, but I have a problem.
I don't use text (tested this, works fine) in the menu, but instaid I use images.

Now my problem with that is that the lavalamp doesn't resize to the full width of the image when you clear your cache (ctrl+f5, or when you first visit the site).

http://www.spiritus-design.be

Do you guys know a good trick?

Cheerzz

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add `display:block` to the image :

```
#menu ul li a img {
border: medium none;
margin-left: 15px;
display:block;
```

}

I am not sure, hopefully it will help

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this after you initialize the lavaLamp plugin:

```
$('.back').width($('.current').children('a').children('img').outerWidth())
```

But for some reason it's not completely filling the width of the image due to some weird position on the nav.

Comment: well, that puts the lavalamp on the right starting point (instaid of in the middle) but it still doesn't get the width right.. so a small step forward ^^